# using instanceof to check if an arrayelement belongs to a certain class

Tags: java, arrays, instanceof

So I made two classes.

1. `Rectangle`
2. `coloredRectangled extends Rectangle`

Than I made an array of Rectangles and inserted this check:

```
if(tabel[i] instanceof coloredRectangle){}
```

Netbeans tells me 'inconvertible types ,requiered coloredRectangle ,found Rectangle'
I thought that with polymorphism it could work. What am i doing wrong?

Code Rectangle:

```
public class Rechthoek implements Printbaar {
protected double lengte,breedte;
private Rechthoek[] tabel;

public Rechthoek(int lengte,int breedte){
    this.lengte=lengte;
    this.breedte=breedte;
}

public String getInfo(){
    return ("De lengte van de rechthoek is "+lengte+" en de breedte is "+breedte+" .");
}

public void schrijfTabel(Rechthoek[] tabel){
    for (int i = 0; i < tabel.length; i++) {
        tabel[i].getInfo();
    }
}
```

// faulty code is in the following method - Rechthoek = Rectangle and kleurRechthoek = coloredRectangle

```
public boolean bevatKleur(Rechthoek[] tabel,String kleur){
    for (int i = 0; i < tabel.length; i++) {
        if(tabel[i] instanceof kleurRechthoek ){
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you're talking about?

Comment: can you show how you declared your array??

Comment: Also, your code would be cleaner if you followed Java naming conventions: `ColoredRectangle`, not `colorRectangle`.

Comment: `tabel[i]` is an array of?

Comment: i guess you should post your `kleurRechthoek` class code as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you (probably) cannot cast from  `tabel[i]` to `coloredRectangle`.

It's stated in the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2) that `instanceof` will cause compilation problems if the above occurs:

> If a cast of the RelationalExpression to the ReferenceType would be
>   rejected as a compile-time error, then the instanceof relational
>   expression likewise produces a compile-time error. In such a
>   situation, the result of the instanceof expression could never be
>   true.

Answer (score 1):

Read about instanceof operator [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html).

Change

```
if(kleurRechthoek instanceof tabel[i] ){
```

to

```
if(tabel[i] instanceof kleurRechthoek){
```

Now that you have edited the question, see ᴍaroun ᴍaroun answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `kleurRechthoek` is a class (I would suggest having all class names start with a capital letter), then you are using the `instanceof` operator incorrectly. It should be used

```
OBJECT instanceof CLASS_NAME
```

so for example

```
new Double(1d) instanceof Number // == true
Double instanceof Number // invalid use, left-hand operator must be an object
Double.class instanceof Number // the compiler will complain here about "Incompatible conditional operand types Class<Double> and Number" since the instanceof check will always return false. However if you do something like : 
((Object) Double.class) instanceof Number // == false
Double.class instanceof Class // == true
Double.class instanceof Class.class // invalid use, right-hand operand must be a class name not an instance of that class object
```

in your case you want to do something like

```
tabel[i] instanceof kleurRechthoek
```

Comment: I have tabel[i] instanceof kleurRechthoek , but i still get the error

Comment: That might mean that there is some problem in the `kleurRechthoek` class, could you post it?

Comment: It is ok ,for some reason my corrected code didnt reupdate . After a save operation the error disappeared. Thx :)